# Can't access the default gateway page on my Sagemcom F@ST 3686 modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have my computer computer plugged to a Sagemcom F@ST 3686 v2 tlc, via Ethernet.

I'm able to access Internet, and ipconfig tells me that the default gateway is `192.168.0.1`, but I can't seem to enter to the config page from my browser.

I'm able to ping that address, though. Funny thing is that I was able to enter the config page the last time I tried to.

I attempted several things to fix this issue, as `/release`, `/flushdns` and `renew`, but nothing seems to work.

Any idea on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Initially I wonder if this router is controlled/delivered by your ISP?
It could be that the web admin interface have been deferred to a location on the internet.

What you may do to see if anything is listening on the internal web inteface is use an old 'quick-and-dirty' approach to see 'if anything' is there, like using telnet with a non-standard port, like in this sample;

```
~$ telnet 192.168.0.1 80
Trying 192.168.0.1...
Connected to 192.168.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout
Server: micro_httpd
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 2021 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public
Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 10:17:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>408 Request Timeout</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#cc9999"><H4>408 Request Timeout</H4>
No request found.
<HR>
<ADDRESS><A HREF="http://www.acme.com/software/micro_httpd/">micro_httpd</A></ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

In this case you will know that there *is* a web server listening on port 80 but it may not want to serve you but defer admin (forward) to another location.
Note the syntax of the telnet 192.168.0.1 80
you are using the non-standard port with telnet to access the web port - sometimes this is written as ipv4-address:portnumber

Comment: The device is a router+modem combo, delivered by my ISP.
I tried telnetting as you said, but it just gave me a blank screen.

Comment: It's tempting to take a step back from technicalities and perhaps call your ISP and ask if you are supposed to be able to administer your own router and if this happens on the router or on/via some other mechanism. Would this approach be feasible for you? Call your ISP?

Comment: If you, for some reason, will not/can not contact the ISP and wants to do more yourself, you do have the following option; But be aware that this assumes that the router is built with a failsafe mechanism (highly likely)(will fall back to local admin). Disconnect from external NW and do a factory reset. After this you should be able to locally administer the router. This will test if local admin were disabled by ISP or perhaps the router got broken.. Depending on how the router/modem is connected to the outside world - WAN/DSL/Coax, you can even try to connect this way, but this gets esoteric.

Comment: I've already factory resetted the modem, but it didn't really work, so I'm assuming it's an ISP problem, after everything I tried to solve it. I'll call them tomorrow and see if they can do something, otherwise I'm completely lost.